# How to close a child activity in a tab activity group android?

Tags: android, activitygroup, android-tabactivity

My parent class open a child activity correctly but when i tried to close this child activity with this.finish() or getCurrentActivity().finish() i get a force close error.  I know using getParent().finish() will close the parent activity, so, this means it is feasible to close child activity.

I search and come to getLocalActivityManager(). i believe this is the key to close a child activity in a tab group. But how to apply this ? I am trying but its fruitless.

here is my method to close the child activity.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.back:

        final LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
        manager.getCurrentActivity().finish();

        break;

    }
}
```

My Logcat

```
12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at package.name.tabgroup.TabGroupActivity.finishFromChild(TabGroupActivity.java:49)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:3259)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at ..itemlist.OdiamListDetails.onClick(OdiamListDetails.java:78)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)


12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)

12-02 21:08:15.494: E/AndroidRuntime(27064):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: only `finish();` does not work?

Comment: It closes the application. force close error